# Does facebook help developers to track "trial pay"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-credits

Under insights > other features > credits, I can see the in-game purchases. Does facebook also help to track Trial pays ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TrialPay has a developer dashboard available which provides test code and reporting to publishers integrating on Facebook. You can read more about it at http://help.trialpay.com/credits/?p=394.

Comment: Thanks! That was a hard to find link.